# Typescript and async initialisation outside protractor it

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, stream, protractor

I read a test configuration from a `CSV` file with `csv-parser`, which behaves asynchronously. When I wrap the parser in a Promise and use it inside my async `it` test case with *await* the configuration data is resolved... outside the 'it' it's not resolved since describe supports no `async` and `module: commonjs` allows no top-level *await*.
The configuration data contains test data which is used to run on an 'it' test case in a loop with different parameters.
So I need a way to:

1. resolve the promise outside the 'it' to get the config data OR
2. to find a way to wait for the `csv-parser` stream/pipe/on to finish before returning config data.

```js
export function initCountryMatrixFromCsv() {
  return new Promise <Map<string, ShopFunction>>((resolve, reject) => {
    const countryShopFunctions = new  Map<string, ShopFunction>();
    countryShopFunctions.set(ALL_FUNCTIONS, new Map<string, ShopFunction>());
    const fs = require('fs');
    const csv = require('csv-parser');

    const parsedCsv = [];

    // behaves async... returns imediately and without the promise countryShopFunctions map is not filled:
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/country_matrix.csv')
      .pipe(csv({ separator: ',' }))
      .on('headers', async (headers) => {
            // some header inits
         }
      )
      .on('data', async (data) => await parsedCsv.push(data))
      .on('end', async () => {
        // init configuration in countryShopFunctions
      });
  });
```

```js
describe('E2E-I18N-CMX: test country matrix', () => {
    // a promise... await not alowed here
    const matrix = initCountryMatrixFromCsv(); 
    
    // not possible since matrix is a promise
    matrix.forEach((shopFunction, roleName) = > {
        it('Test ' + role, async (){
            // perform test with shopFunction params
            // first place to resolve the promise ... but i need it outside the it
            const matrix2 = await initCountryMatrixFromCsv(); 
        });
    });
});
```

I tried several variants with and without promise but all ended up with an empty map when I don't use Promise with await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Protractor with Jasmine (although it doesn't really matter that much).

Jasmine will try to resolve the test cases before your actual `initCountryMatrixFromCsv` method is resolved.
The reasoning behind this is simple, it needs to know how many tests are there as part of it's setup.

I ran into the same problem in our tests and the fix was to read the CSV file sync.

For this I have used the [csv-load-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-load-sync) npm package and then read the file:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as loader from 'csv-load-sync';
import * as path from 'path';

readTestDataCsvSync() {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'TestData.csv');
    try {
      if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        return loader(path.join(__dirname, 'TestData.csv'));
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw new Error(`Couldn't load the test cases CSV file: ${err}`);
    }
  }
```

Now you can just have your tests like before:

```
describe('E2E-I18N-CMX: test country matrix', () => {
    const matrix = readTestDataCsvSync(); 
    
    matrix.forEach((shopFunction, roleName) = > {
        it('Test ' + role, async (){
            // your test
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the initialization function in a beforeAll/beforeEach block. The matrix is then available in each it

```
describe('your test', () => {
  let matrix2;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    matrix2 = await initCountryMatrixFromCsv();
  });

  it('my test', () => {
    expect(matrix2).toBeTruthy(); // do more verifications ...
  });
});
```

Also make sure to `resolve` the promise in the function. I guess you want it to resolve in the on('end')

Comment: yes i resolve the promise in on('end'). I also already tried beforeAll/beforeEach and inside the 'it' it is resolved but not outside the 'it'. So i can not use matrix.forEach outside the it.